# Angular AppComponent Values not updated in constructor

Tags: angular, ejs-schedule

I have AppComponent class defined as

```
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('scheduleObj')
    public scheduleObj!: ScheduleComponent;
    ----
    ---
    private businessID : string = '999';
    ----
    private currentTimeZone : string = 'Europe/London';
```

then I have constructor defined as

```
constructor()   {
      console.log("Constructor Called");
      this.businessID = '12';
      this.currentTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    }
```

Finally I have a Query Object which is passing data to backend APIs

```
private dataQuery: Query = new Query().from("Appointment").addParams('business_id', this.getBusinessID()).addParams('timezone',this.currentTimeZone);
```

When I check the Data received in the Backend, I can see this

```
body: '{"table":"Table1","params":{"location_id":"999","timezone":"Europe/London","StartDate":"2022-05-21T14:00:00.000Z","EndDate":"2022-05-28T14:00:00.000Z"},"location_id":"999","timezone":"Europe/London","StartDate":"2022-05-21T14:00:00.000Z","EndDate":"2022-05-28T14:00:00.000Z"}',
  isBase64Encoded: false
```

so the values assigned in constructor is not passed to backend.
Any clue as to what needs to be done in order to pass the values to goto backend

Comment: Values which should come to backend API should be business_id=12, timezone="Australia/Sydney"

Comment: From where do you call the backend API ? 
You could check the order of execution by having breakpoints inside constructor and in the place where you call the API.

Comment: Query Object contains the values passed to every API Call in ejs-schedule object